# initialize div after creating jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have following code to show div on page

```
<div id="all_users">

 <div id=user11 userid=11 class=innertxt><img src=images/images.jpg width=50 height=50>    
 <strong>User11</strong>
  <ul> <li>Email: user11@uaer11.com</li>
  <li> <input type=checkbox id=select11 value=11 class=selectit /></li>
  </ul> </div>
 <div class="float_break"></div>

  </div>
```

following code work fine and print "test in log window"

```
         $('#all_users .selectit').click(function() {
         console.log("test");
         });
```

but when i add div from following code, it didn't show "test in log windows" mean this click event is not activated

```
         var new_data_var = $('<div class="innertxt" userid="1" id="user1"> <img height="50" width="50" src="images/images.jpg"><strong>Test User 01</strong><ul><li>User ID: 1</li> <li>Email: user1@nodomain.com</li><li style="padding-top: 5px;"><input type="checkbox" class="selectit" value="1" id="select1"><label for="select1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Select it.</label></li></ul></div>');
       $('#all_users').append(new_data_var);
```

event is not called ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)():

> Binds a handler to an event (like
>   click) for all current - **and
>   future** - matched element.

For example:

```
$('#all_users .selectit').live('click', function() {
    console.log("test");
});
```

Right now you are using [click](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click)() which delegates to [bind](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind)().

The main difference is that live, contrary to bind, works also with newly created DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

**[live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** method must do the trick there:

```
  $('#all_users .selectit').live('click', function() {
    console.log("test");
  });
```

> Description: Attach a handler to the
>   event for all elements which match the
>   current selector, now or in the
>   future.

**Source:** http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1):

you should check that your binding the click after the dom element is created or replace `bind` with `live` which behave similarly but also affect not yet existing element.

ps: your html attribute values should be quoted. eg, `type=checkbox` => `type="checkbox"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the `click` event before you create the input box, the click event will not be registered - it will only register the click event for DOM elements that exist at that time. You can either create the input box before calling `$('#all_users .selectit').click(function() { ...` or by using the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function as others have suggested, which will attach the click event for all elements that match the selector and all elements in the future.